# how to get the result map with required fields with node js

Tags: node.js

i wrote the node js get api with restaurant details. result is fine. how to get the map with required fields? bulk of fields are there but i required 2 fields only restaurant name and address. i am learning node js.

```
app.get('/restaurants', async (req, res, next) => {
       const city = 'vizag'
       try {
           const {data} = await axios.get(
           
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+${city}&fields=name&key=AIzaSyBHqf23r_JrVbjXWUFSR1WW06IZQtsj4d8`
           )
           res.json(data)
        
           } 
         catch (err) {
          next(err)
        }
        });
```

result is:

```
 "results": [
    {
      "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
      "formatted_address": "10-28-3, Waltair Main Rd, Waltair Uplands, Uplands, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530003, India",
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 17.7205589,
          "lng": 83.3122454
        },
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 17.72188482989272,
            "lng": 83.31359027989271
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 17.71918517010728,
            "lng": 83.31089062010727
          }
        }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/restaurant-71.png",
      "name": "The Eatery",
      "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true
      },

]
```

required output:

```
    "results": [
    {
      "formatted_address": "10-28-3, Waltair Main Rd, Waltair Uplands, Uplands, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530003, India",
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this?

```
try {
    const data = await axios.get(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+${city}&fields=name&key=AIzaSyBHqf23r_JrVbjXWUFSR1WW06IZQtsj4d8`
    )
    const info = data.data.results
    const formatted_address = info.map(a => ({ formatted_address: a.formatted_address, name: a.name }))
    res.json(formatted_address)
}
catch (err) {
    next(err)
}
```

Comment: great working tq so much ...i have small doubt how to get two fileds

Comment: Which fields you need?

Comment: rest-rent name and address

Comment: like
"results": [
     {
       "name": "Dharani Restaurant",
      "formatted_address": "Hotel Dasapalla, Town Kotha Rd, Suryabagh, Jagadamba Junction, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530020, India",
      },
     {
       "name": "WelcomCafe Oceanic Restaurant",
      "formatted_address": "10-28-3, Waltair Main Rd, Waltair Uplands, Uplands, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530003, India"
      },

Comment: Check the answer again please. I made the change,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array. This map function will return new Array.

```
// Assuming results is a json with key results
const results = res.json(data)
results["results"] = results["results"].map((obj) => ({"formatted_address": obj.formatted_address}));
```

Comment: hi thanks for response tq so much but i am trying this same code all fields is comming

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet where you are using the map function.

Comment: https://ideone.com/pCP8UM try running the following code snippet. I am able to get the expected result